# Enumerate all current sheet names in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have code that takes user input and uses that to determine which worksheet is the "target" worksheet to be copied, but this takes a long time to run the code over and over for the 30+ sheets in the workbook.
I'm not sure where to begin coding something that would automatically take the data from one worksheet at a time, copy it to a new sheet, run some more code, and then repeat the process until done.  Below is the current code.

```
'Prompt User: Which sheet on Dataworkbook should be copied
    Dim mySheet As String
    mySheet = Application.InputBox("Enter a sheet name")
'User provides input

'Data copied from source workbook page from "Dataworkbook" specified by user
    x.Sheets(mySheet).Range("A1:z28").Copy
    y.Sheets("Test").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'Copy of data appears on new sheet created when running macro
```

Essentially I want this process to be automated, and to execute the same set of commands for every sheet currently in Dataworkbook, but I want it to stop when it reaches the end (no duplicates).
I'm very new at VBA (just started messing around with it yesterday) and would really appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple iteration which can be acheived with the `For Each ... Next` structured loop.

Iterate over the `Worksheets` collection in the `x` Workbook:

```
        'Prompt User: Which sheet on Dataworkbook should be copied
        '    Dim mySheet As String
        '    mySheet = Application.InputBox("Enter a sheet name")
        'User provides input

        Dim ws as Worksheet 
        For each ws in x.Worksheets

            'Data copied from source workbook page from "Dataworkbook" specified by user
            ws.Range("A1:z28").Copy
            y.Sheets("Test").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

            '### Put the rest of your code here to manipulate the data on ws
            '
            MsgBox ws.Range("A1").value 'etc.
            '
            '
            '###

        Next
```

Documentation on the For Each... Next:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

A full list of VBA statements documentation which is also very useful:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: David, the code you shared works really well, but I need to execute another set of code for each individual worksheet.  So, I need to copy the information from Dataworkbook-Sheet, run the code, then copy the information from Dataworkbook-sheet2 and run the code, copy the information from Dataworkbook-sheet3, etc. if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Had to do a little bit of tweaking but I got the code to do exactly what I wanted it to do.